# Passing owner reference to created objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I need to pass the reference of a view controller to one of the object it creates. I have the following piece of code where I instantiate my object

```
//Method in OwnerClass
- (void) someMethod{
    SomeObject *obj = [[SomeObject alloc] init];
    obj.instanceVar = self.iVar;
}
```

Now in SomeObject I want to access the owner(instance of OwnerClass) which created it.

```
//Method in SomeObject
- (void) callback{
    [ownerObj callMethod] //ownerObj is the instance of OwnerClass that created an instance of SomeObj
}
```

I want to know how do I access the instance of OwnerClass inside instance of SomeObject. Of course, I can simply write a property inside SomeObject like

```
@property(nonatomic) OwnerClass *ownerReference;
```

and assign it when I'm initializing SomeObject and access it from there.

What I want to is if there is any standard way of getting the owner. Something similar to

```
self.parentViewController
```

which is Apple's standard way of obtaining the parent of a particular view controller.

Comment: Yes, there're several ways like delegate, block callback, notification. It's not about transferring owner, but they are the way to access other classes method or properties.

Comment: @trick14 of course, I can use delegates, callback etc., but they all require some additional coding from me.Also, I'm not talking about other classes - I'm talking about the owner that created the object. To be clear as I said in my last statement, does Apple provide any standard mechanisms to solve the problem.

Comment: @NazMir, _"but they all require some additional coding from me"_, so you are saying you already know a few working solution to your problem, but your are too lazy committing any of them?

Comment: @holex if you have nothing constructive then better stay away from the question. If you put enough thought into reading the question you might have understood that I was looking for a standard way of doing this. Something that advocated by Apple and considered a best practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no general, formal concept of "Ownership" for objects in Objective C or the iOS SDK. So no, there is no standard "magic" way of doing what you want.

Comment: Ok. In that case can you suggest a good approach to solve my problem or should I pass a weak reference of the owner to the created object?

Comment: I personally use the property based approach you suggested yourself whenever I am in this situation. Whether you want a weak or a strong reference probably depends on the particular circumstances, i.e. whether your owned object can potentially outlast its owner and how well it can cope with being "orphaned" so to speak.

Comment: Markus - thanks for the answers and comments. I will wait for a day or two to see if someone advocates a different/magical approach. If not I will accept your answer

Answer (score -1):

it's wrong to pass a reference from view to another view..
if you want to call method in another controller you can use protocols and delegate

Comment: ...and why on the Earth would it be wrong to pass a reference from a view to another?

Comment: first it is not secure wise to have object ..
second why to have all the object when u need only one method
third this object will always be in memory until the main object in the memory "circular loop"

Comment: when was the _first_ exactly? in the 1960s...?

Comment: well what about second and third??

Comment: _second_, what do you think we pass when we delegate a class? yes, we are passing the reference only which is **not wrong** – but there are thousands of other situation when we pass the reference from a class to another; _third_, the object is released when there is no more strong reference to it... overall I think you would have some confusion about what _reference_ means, and you may need to update your knowledge about memory management as well. that is not _Turbo Pascal 6.0_ anymore.